# Replace all characters EXCEPT whitespace in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Im looking for a regular expression to use with javascript's string.replace function to replace all characters in a string with a new character, except whitespace.

For example, this string:
"A string of words and spaces"

Would become this string:
"# ###### ## ##### ### ######"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a regex replacement on `\S` globally:

```js
var input = "A string of words and spaces";
var output = input.replace(/\S/g, "#");
console.log(input + "\n" + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\S` to match any non-whitespace character.

https://regex101.com/r/9jY2hn/1

```js
const regex = /\S/gm;
const str = `A string of words and spaces`;
const subst = `#`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Regex (not recommended):

```
const phrase = "A string of words and spaces"
const word_replacement = '#'
const array_phrase = [...phrase]
const replaced_array_phrase = array_phrase.map(word => {
  console.log(word)
  return word === " "? " ": word_replacement
})
const phrase_replaced_string = replaced_array_phrase.join('')

console.log(array_phrase)
console.log(replaced_array_phrase)
console.log(phrase_replaced_string)

//one liner
const replacedOneLine = [..."A string of words and spaces"].map(word => word === " "? " ": "#").join('')
console.log(replacedOneLine)
```